# How to make scroll-chaining work between an iframe scrollable div and the iframe's parent in iOS?

Tags: css, ios, iframe, overscroll

This [website](https://www.sbb.ch/de/freizeit-ferien/destinationen/staedte-laender-europa.html) uses an iframe to embed a web-component map application showing train connections through Europe. When clicking a line on the map, an overlay container opens, showing details of the corresponding train connection. Depending on the content of the container it will have a scrollbar. On iOS devices (all browsers), when scrolling to the top or bottom of the overlay container, it will not trigger the desired over-scroll event on the parent website, which can cause getting stuck without being able to scroll above or below the iframe (e.g. on devices with small screens). On Android this seems to work without problems.

Is there a work-around for iOS devices?